# Merge git repo as subdir

Tags: git

I have three dirs with git repo :

```
-dir1
-dir2
-dir3
```

I want move dir1 and dir2 into dir3 :

```
-dir3
 -dir1
 -dir2
```

How i can merge git repo from dir1 and dir2 into dir3?
I need save dir1 and dir2 vcs commits in dir3 history

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking. You have 3 git repositories and you're trying to move the repositories into another while keeping history of the originals? git subtree?

Comment: I have 3 different code modules with different repo. Then I want to transfer two modules to the third without losing the history of commits. Can i do this with git subtree? I initially understood git subtree as nested repositories, not how to include repositories in the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use git subtree here.

First you have to read in the repository history by fetching them.

```
../dir3 $ git remote add rdir1 ../dir1
../dir3 $ git fetch rdir1
```

Then add the subtree of the remote to your repository.

```
../dir3 $ git switch master
../dir3 $ git subtree add -P dir1 rdir1/master
```

This takes the tree of the remote branch `rdir1/master` and sets it to the local path `dir1` so it becomes a subtree of your dir3 repo.

Then cleanup the remotes when finished

```
../dir3 $ git remote remove rdir1
```

Repeat for any other repos you wish to import.